# `Insufficient-allowance` when sending transaction

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm using UniswapV2Router02 contract and here is the problem.
When I try to call the `swap` function in Remix IDE it shows me

```
execution reverted: Dai/insufficient-allowance
```

Although I have DAI in the account that I'm sending the transaction with.
Here is the full code Click on this link and copy paste the code in your Remix IDE (Ignore the additional files if you're not familiar with codesandbox just the opened file code will be enough :) )


#### FULL CODE

and here is the values that i'm passing to `swap` function (since I'm using Remix tools to do it, I'm just assigning them here so that it's more clear)

```
_tokenIn: 0xc7AD46e0b8a400Bb3C915120d284AafbA8fc4735
_tokenOut: 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984
_amountIn: 100000
_minAmountOut: 0000001// I guess I’m doing something wrong here please let me know if it's wrong
_to: 0x9b6582f3b8c262B062BDC779064F16aB026eE566// the account that i'm sure has DAI
```

I'm using Injected provider (MetaMask) for ENVIRONMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call approve function. You need to approve DAI spender as contract address from your wallet account.

Here, `spender` is `contract address`

`amount` is `_amountIn * 1e18`

And you need to approve from your wallet account

Also remember, you have to send this transaction to DAI contract.

DAI.approve(spender, amount, {"from":account})

Comment: So I should not approve it in the contract, right?

Comment: Therefore the I cannot do the transaction from Remix IDE since I cannot approve it outside of contract

Comment: Ok so now when I call approve function outside of contract (in metamask) i get `Fail with error UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY`

Comment: I'm trying to swap DAI for UNI

Comment: approve never gives error like this. You  must be doing something else, please share which transaction are you making.

Note: you have to send transaction to DAI contract

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't approve the contract to spend your DAI, here's the method you need to call to fix it https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-